# wordpress custom query with variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, variables

I'm trying to make a custom page in wordpress that shows 2 authors.
I have a custom query because i need to show an author image and bio.
My query is now this:

```
    <?php 

        global $wpdb;

        $authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename, meta_value, meta_key, display_name 
                                            FROM $wpdb->users, $wpdb->usermeta 
                                            WHERE user_nicename = 'nick' AND umeta_id = 53");

        foreach($authors as $author) {
            ?>
            <div class="author">
                <div class="authorimage" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $author->meta_value; ?>');" >
                </div>
                <div class="authorinfo">
                    <?php
                    $username = $author->user_nicename;
                    echo $author->display_name; ?><br /><?php
                        $bios = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename, meta_value, meta_key, display_name 
                                                        FROM $wpdb->users, $wpdb->usermeta 
                                                        WHERE user_nicename = %d
                                                        AND umeta_id = 43", $username);

                    foreach($bios as $bio) {    
                        echo $bio->meta_value;
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

I use 2 queries because i could not figure out how i get 2 meta values in one result.
Everything works great but in the second query `WHERE user_nicename= %d` is not working.
it does not show anything in echo `$bio->metavalue`.
but if i hardcode `WHERE user_nicename = "andre"` it works

Comment: %d is for decimal value, change it to %s and try

Comment: Still not working, if i put echo "test"; inside the foreach (bios as bio) it is not showing.

Comment: try echo of the sql query, this way u'll be able to see what query it makes. then run it directly in mysqladmin to see what result u get. And it seems ur 1st query is is returning no record. you can do `print_r($bios);` to chk if there is any record return. it will display an array with record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with some help.

```
    $users = "('nick', 'roy')";
    global $wpdb;
        $tableB2 = "SELECT user_id, max(umeta_id) maxid
                        FROM  art_usermeta b
                        WHERE meta_key = 'author_profile_picture'
                        GROUP BY user_id";

        $tableB1 = "SELECT a.user_id, maxid, meta_value, meta_key
                        FROM ($tableB2) a 
                        INNER JOIN art_usermeta b on b.user_id=a.user_id and b.umeta_id=maxid and meta_key='author_profile_picture'";

        $tableC2 = "SELECT user_id, max(umeta_id) maxid
                        FROM  art_usermeta b
                        WHERE meta_key = 'description'
                        GROUP BY user_id";

        $tableC1 = "SELECT a.user_id, maxid, meta_value, meta_key
                        FROM ($tableC2) a 
                        INNER JOIN art_usermeta c on c.user_id=c.user_id and c.umeta_id=maxid and meta_key='description'";

        $sql     = "SELECT ID, user_nicename, b.meta_value bvalue, b.meta_key bkey, display_name, c.meta_value cvalue, c.meta_key ckey
                        FROM art_users a
                        INNER JOIN ($tableB1) b  ON b.user_id=id AND b.meta_key = 'author_profile_picture'
                        INNER JOIN ($tableC1) c ON c.user_id=id AND c.meta_key = 'description'
                        WHERE user_nicename in $users";
```

This query returns the description of the user_nicename, display_name the description of the author and photo url.
It also checks the highest number of description and photo url that if those get updated it gets the newest one.

Still thanks for your help and sorry for my english.